# Creating raster stack from xarray in Python

Tags: python, rasterio, numpy, xarray

I am trying to create a raster stack from an xarray dataset which I obtained from multiple NetCDF files.

```
import netCDF4 as nc
import rasterio as rio
import numpy as np
import xarray as xr
import os

fpath = '/home/sst/2015'
pattern = '*.nc'
filelist = []


for root, dirs, files in os.walk(fpath):
for name in files:
    filelist.append(os.path.join(fpath,name))

ds = xr.open_mfdataset(eflist, concat_dim='time', parallel = True) # netCDF data

ds_data = ds.sel(time='2015')['SST']   # xarray dataset with dimension 365x3600x7200.
```

By looping over the 3D xarray following code writes 365 files to HDD and later I can read and stack those files.

```
from rasterio.transform import from_origin
transform = from_origin(-180,90, 0.05, 0.05)

fpath = '/home/sst/sst_tif'
fname = 'sst_array_'
extname = '.tiff'
timedf = ds.time    # time dimension to loop over

for i in range(len(timedf)):
    np_array = np.array(ds_data[i])
    iname = str(i)
    fwname = fpath + fname + iname + extname

    sst_tif = rio.open(fwname,
                    'w',
                   driver = 'GTiff',
                   height = 3600,
                   width = 7200,
                   dtype = np_array.dtype,
                   count = 1,
                   crs = 'EPSG:4326',
                   transform = transform)

    sst_tif.write(np_array, 1)
    sst_tif.close()
```

However this takes a very long time as it creates 365 files on HDD. Is there any way I can create this raster stack in memory and do further processing without having to write it to file/s on HDD? I am trying to obtain functionality similar to that of `stack` available in `raster` package of `R`.